# Modifying Date&Time generate a code signing error

Tags: ios, macos, certificate, provisioning-profile

To test some functionalities on my iOs app I had to change the date on the simulator to the 01/01/2021, the only way to do that is to change the date on the macOS first, I had to do that with the system preferences. But when I start testing  I get several errors related to the code signing `Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: xx.xx.xx" expired on 11. Dec 2020.` I can understand that, cause the date is superior that the expire date of the provisioning profile, but normally when I change again the date to the current date that is inferior to the provisioning profile it have to work, but wasn't the case, this some staff I tried to do but no one solved my problems

- change the date to the current date and restart the machine.
- delete all provisioning profile, delete the Apple Id in Xcode and add it again
- check all build settings if there is a problem on them but everything is ok
- delete all derived data close Xcode, restart it again, clean and build again the project

here is list of the errors I'm getting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If somebody had the same error, the solution that It worked by luck and I don't understand why is that when I was pulling changes from the master branch of my project all errors disappeared. I think it charged previous setups